# Run a method if it has not already ran with the current class?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class that I am writing and I have a method that I would like to run once per initiation of the class. Normally this would go in the construct method, but I only need it to run when I call certain methods, not all.

How would you all recommend I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a private property `$methodHasBeenRun` which has a defualt value of `FALSE`, and set it to `TRUE` in the method. At the start of the method, do:

```
if ($this->methodHasBeenRun) return;
$this->methodHasBeenRun = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify exactly why you only want to run a given method once when certain methods are called, but I am going to make a guess that you're loading or initializing something (perhaps data that comes from a DB), and you don't need to waste cycles each time.

@DaveRandom provided a great answer that will work for sure.  Here is another way you can do it:

```
class foo {
    protected function loadOnce() {
            // This will be initialied only once to NULL
            static $cache = NULL;

            // If the data === NULL, load it
            if($cache === NULL) {
                    echo "loading data...\n";
                    $cache = array(
                            'key1' => 'key1 data',
                            'key2' => 'key2 data',
                            'key3' => 'key3 data'
                    );
            }

            // Return the data
            return $cache;
    }

    // Use the data given a key
    public function bar($key) {
            $data = $this->loadOnce();
            echo  $data[$key] . "\n";
    }
}

$obj = new foo();

// Notice "loading data" only prints one time
$obj->bar('key1');
$obj->bar('key2');
$obj->bar('key3');
```

The reason this works is that you declare your cache variable as `static`.  There are several different ways to do this as well.  You could make that a member variable of the class, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend this version

```
class example {
    function __construct($run_magic = false) {
        if($run_magic == true) {
            //Run your method which you want to call at initializing
        }
        //Your normale code         
    }
}
```

so if you do not want to run it create the class like

```
new example();
```

if you want

```
new example(true);
```